# Database query gives no error in Console but in Controller class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my controller which should give me the last updated post in a specific category.

```
def set_subcategory_meta_data(category_param)
  post = Post.where("category = ?", category_param).order("updated_at").last
  @last_post_title = post.title
  @last_post_user_name = 'JohnDoe20181827'
  @last_post_update_time = '(25.08.2018, 16:08)'
  @post_count = Post.where("category = ?", category_param).count
  @comment_count = 999
  @last_post_path = user_path(User.first)
  @last_post_user_path = user_path(User.last)
end
```

It doesnt work and gives me a nil:class for post. But it works just fine in Rails console on command line.

I have no idead what I am doing wrong here...

```
irb(main):010:0> post.title="hey he euy"
=> "hey he euy"
irb(main):011:0> post.save
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 64], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "posts" WHERE LOWER("posts"."title") = LOWER($1) AND "posts"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["title", "hey he euy"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Update (1.0ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "title" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "posts"."id" = $3  [["title", "hey he euy"], ["updated_at", "2018-09-11 15:49:43.758079"], ["id", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
=> true
irb(main):012:0> Post.where("category = ?", "ruby-on-rails/developers").order("updated_at").last.title
  Post Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (category = 'ruby-on-rails/developers') ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "hey he euy"
```

Comment: Check whether `category_param` is nil or not. It seems it is *nil*

Comment: Hi thank you I found out that I had no entry for a sepcific category thats why the query result was empty and post was nil. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It doesnt work and gives me a nil:class for post. But it works just
>   fine in Rails console on command line.

The problem with your method is that the `category_param` is *nil* or there is no record with that specific `category_param` which results in *nil post*. Make sure that the `category_param` is **not nil** and an existing category, so that the query will return a record.

*OR*

You can just rewrite this line

```
@last_post_title = post.title
```

as

```
@last_post_title = post.title if post
```

to avoid the error

Comment: It was because the query didnt give back a record so ``post`` was actually nil not the ``category_param``. I changed it so that I give default values for the variables instead of calling method on the `post` variable and it works without changing anything about the `category_param`. There was one category which had 0 records and this gave me a nil `post`